# <address> tag text alignment?

Tags: css, html

In address tag.. first line text is going to right with other fields. How make first line also to left?

```css
    .formLayout fieldset {
      border: 0;
      padding: 0;
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      margin-left: 0px;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .main address {
      font-style: normal;
      text-align: left;
    }
    address {
      white-space: pre-wrap;
    }
```

```html
<fieldset class="Normal">
  <address>
            <span id="AddressLabelHome">test test
                    222 Main Street111
                    Dallas TX  78900</span>
      </address>
</fieldset>
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't `.address` in your CSS be `address`?

Comment: Are you aware the address element is not for postal addresses? https://developers.whatwg.org/sections.html#the-address-element

Comment: "The address element must not be used to represent arbitrary addresses (e.g. postal addresses), unless those addresses are in fact the relevant contact information."

Comment: @Michael_B actualy it is `address`

Comment: try `white-space: pre-line;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `white-space: pre-line;` instead.

**pre-wrap** Sequences of whitespace are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

**pre-line** Sequences of whitespace are collapsed. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

```css
    .formLayout fieldset {
      border: 0;
      padding: 0;
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      margin-left: 0px;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .main address {
      font-style: normal;
      text-align: left;
    }
    address {
       word-wrap: break-word;
       white-space: pre-line;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="formLayout">
<fieldset class="Normal">
  <address>
            <span id="AddressLabelHome">test test
                    222 Main Street111
                    Dallas TX  78900</span>
      </address>
</fieldset>
</div>
```